# dispatcher invoke goes to not responding after application idle c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, window, dispatcher

I have main application and I am calling external application through separate thread.

```
 Thread thread = new Thread(this.StartExternalApp);
 thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
 thread.Start();
```

I keep the both main app and external app idle for 10 mins, Then If I try to click on Save from external app then we invoke main application dispatcher invoke

```
userInterfaceDispatcher.Invoke
```

then both applications goes to not responding.

**Note - But it works in following 2 scenarios**

1. After both apps idle, If user performs any UI action on main application and clicks on save in external app then dispatcher invoke works.
2. After both apps idle, If we show messagebox before dispatcher invoke, then it's working.

Seems to be we need to some how awake dispatcher/main thread through user interaction after certain idle time.

How to resolve above issue, through programmatically? I mean without showing messagebox or any UI interaction.

Comment: What kind of *Dispatcher* are you referring to? The WPF Dispatcher (System.Windows.Threading)? What kind of application is the *external* one? Or what kind of Synchronization provider are you using when you *click on Save from external app*? Can you show that code? (Maybe also a description of how these two apps are supposed to interoperate).

Comment: I am using windows dispatcher. Just I am using Application.Current.Dispacher.Invoke(SaveRecordsInDatabase). Just to perform any database save I need to switch to UI thread.

Comment: So, you're using the WPF Dispatcher (PresentationFramework) to Synchronize a WinForms app. These use different Synchronization providers. What is *click on Save* doing, in practice?

Comment: Yes Jim Correct. When we click on Save in external app -> It comes to Save event -> there we are  trying to save items into the database using dispatcher.Invoke. It goes to Not Responding exactly when Invoke calls.

Comment: JIm, I would like to add one more point. In main application there are so many modules. In some modules, we have Application Idle event is there. There some code is running. The tricky thing is, If we disable all application idle events, I am not facing any issue. But If I disable application Idle events, it breaks other functionality.

Comment: I'm kind of surprised it can actually work reliably in *normal conditions*. But, I don't use this kind of model for interop (never have, never will), so I'm not sure what other kind of pitfalls it can hide. See whether you can pass a `Progress<T>` object as delegate that can capture the original SynchronizationContext. It can be used with a Thread (eventually). -- Still no idea what code is run and what is doing (not the *intention*, what are the actual lines of code you have there).

Comment: Seems to be the issue could be -  standard application message loop is paused. After both application are idle for some time, even application idle event is also not working. If I do Application.Run(New Form()) then it starts working. Can we start Message loop without Application.Run